# How do I replicate a table to all nodes in a DB2 DPF instance?

Tags: db2, dbf

I have a dpf instance with a few large tables, which are partitioned, and a number of small tables which are not.  I'd like the small table to fully exist on each node of the partition for performance reasons.  How do I make db2 fully replicate these small tables to each node?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching?  Google "db2 replicated tables" and the first hit is a [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0005316.htm) to the specific documentation for replicated MQTs.

That said: replicated MQTs should be an exception.  I've been working with DPF (EEE) for over 10 years, and the number of times that a replicated MQT has become a necessity is very small.  DB2 is very smart about shipping broadcasting dimension table data out to the database partitions where the fact tables are located, and this data is cached locally.

Comment: I was expecting to find some built in property of the table, rather than setting up MQTs.  I've now setup the MQTs, the query optimizer is using them, and performance is 8x better.